# Normal Distribution Question about tiers answer verification

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> A study of data collected at a tyre factory shows that a batch of $8000$
>   tyres have a  mean wear life of $35000$ km with a standard deviation of
>   $7000$ km. Assuming a Normal  Distribution, estimate:
>
> (i) How many tyres will wear out before $30000$ km?
>
> (ii) How many tyres will continue for more than $45000$ km before
>   wearing out?

$X = 8,000\\
U= 35,000\\
SD= 7,000\\
\frac{X-\mu}\sigma$

(i) First we find the $Z$ score$$\frac{35,000-30,0000}{7,000}=0.71$$
$Z$-score$= .2580$

Tyres to wear out$$8000(.5-.2580)=1936$$
(ii) Tiers to continue more than $45,000$

This is where I am stuck as I am not sure how to go about

I am not sure if I just repeat the same steps as before and just change the values 
$$\frac{45,000-35,000}{7000}=1.42$$

$Z$-score $= .4207$

Answer is$$8000(.5-.4207)=634.3$$

---

Should I subtract the first answer from $X~(8000-1936)$ first as we already know that these tiers will fail?

Comment: You need to find out the number of tyres that **will fail before $30,000\text{ km}$** in the first part. No need to subtract.

Comment: Here is a guide to [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) to typeset your math equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)~P(X\le30,000)=P\left(Z\le\frac{30,000-35,000}{7,000}=\color{red}-\frac57\right)=P(Z\ge5/7)=0.5-P(0\le Z\le5/7)$

$5/7\approx0.71$ and $P(0\le Z\le0.71)$ is $0.2611$ from the table. Thus, the number of tyres is $8,000(0.5-0.2611)\approx1,911$. The difference in our answers is because I had access to a more refined value of $P(0\le Z\le5/7)$.

$(2)~P(X\ge45,000)=P\left(Z\ge\frac{45,000-35,000}{7,000}=\frac{10}7\right)=0.5-P(0\le Z\le10/7)$

$10/7\approx1.43$ and $P(0\le Z\le1.43)$ is $0.4236$ from the table. Thus, the number of tyres is $8,000(0.5-0.4236)\approx611$. The difference in our answers is because I had access to a more refined value of $P(0\le Z\le10/7)$.

---

There is no requirement to subtract the above answer from $8,000$, as $8,000-1,911$ will give the number of tyres that wear out after $30,000\text{ km}$ which is not required to be found.